# Can you connect to PaylPal's REST API From 3rd Party Apps

Tags: rest, authentication, paypal

I am looking at building a product that integrates with PayPal new REST API. I can't find any information on connecting to other PayPal users accounts to make requests on their behalf. All I can find suggests that all of my users will have to login to developer.paypal.com and create their own App, and plug those credentials into the product I am building.

It seems like their should be a way to authenticate to a user's account and make requests on their behalf.  Is there?

Comment: I'm interested in this too. There does not seem to be a clear way of doing this in the new rest api.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does have a way to authorize a third party to make calls on another party's behalf. There is even an API that can do this. The most straightforward way is for you to provide them your API username and they authorize you to run calls on their behalf and you call with their email address as a parameter (at least in Classic, REST may have a different method)

PayPal [has a guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/ht_invoicing-3p/) to all this on the Developer page (it's too extensive to excerpt).

Comment: thank you, but that is for the Classic API not the new REST API